# Double wav speed with c program

Tags: c, file, file-io, wav

I have create a program in c that read wav file with getchar.

I run the program like this ./wavproc < sound.wav

I would like to double sound's speed and create a new wav file with putchar.

I have to run the program like this ./wavproc < sound.wav > soundX2.wav

It is necessary to use only getchar and putchar because it's an exercise.

I put the code I have written

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){

unsigned char buffer4[4];
unsigned char buffer2[2];

unsigned int size_of_file;
unsigned int size_of_format_chunck;
unsigned int wave_type_format;
unsigned int mono_stereo;   
unsigned int sample_rate;
unsigned int bytes_per_second;
unsigned int block_alignment;
unsigned int bits_per_sample;
unsigned int size_of_data_chunck;   
char riff[4];
char wave[4];
char fmt[4];
char data[4];

int i;


char c;

while(1) {
    c = getchar();
    putchar(c);
    if(c == EOF)
        break;
}   




//read bytes 1-4 to check RIFF
for(i=0;i<4;i++){
  riff[i] = getchar();
}

if(riff[0] != 'R') {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error! \"RIFF\" not found\n");
    return 1;
} else if(riff[1] != 'I') {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error! \"RIFF\" not found\n");   
            return 1;
} else if(riff[2] != 'F') {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error! \"RIFF\" not found\n");   
            return 1;
} else if(riff[3] != 'F') {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error! \"RIFF\" not found\n");   
            return 1;
}

//read bytes 5-8 for size of file
for(i=0;i<4;i++) {
    buffer4[i] = getchar();
}
size_of_file = buffer4[0] | (buffer4[1]<<8) | (buffer4[2]<<16) | (buffer4[3]<<24);
fprintf(stderr, "size of file: %d\n",size_of_file);


//read bytes 9-12 to check WAVE 
for(i=0; i<4; i++) {
    wave[i] = getchar();
}

if(wave[0] != 'W') {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error! \"WAVE\" not found\n");
            return 1;
    } else if(wave[1] != 'A') {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error! \"WAVE\" not found\n");
            return 1;
    } else if(wave[2] != 'V') {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error! \"WAVE\" not found\n");
            return 1;
    } else if(wave[3] != 'E') {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error! \"WAVE\" not found\n");
            return 1;
    }

//read bytes 13-16 to check fmt
    for(i=0; i<4; i++) {
            fmt[i] = getchar();
    }

    if(fmt[0] != 'f') {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error! \"fmt \" not found\n");
            return 1;
    } else if(fmt[1] != 'm') {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error! \"fmt \" not found\n");
            return 1;
    } else if(fmt[2] != 't') {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error! \"fmt \" not found\n");
            return 1;
    } else if(fmt[3] != ' ') {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error! \"fmt \" not found\n");
            return 1;
    }

//read bytes 17-20 for size of format chunck
for(i=0; i<4; i++) {
    buffer4[i] = getchar();
}
size_of_format_chunck = buffer4[0] | (buffer4[1]<<8) | (buffer4[2]<<16) | (buffer4[3]<<24);
fprintf(stderr, "size of format chunck: %d\n",size_of_format_chunck);

if(size_of_format_chunck != 16) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error! size of format chunck should be 16\n");
    return 1;
}

//read bytes 21-22 for wave type format
    for(i=0; i<2; i++) {
            buffer2[i] = getchar();
    }
    wave_type_format = buffer2[0] | (buffer2[1]<<8);
    fprintf(stderr, "WAVE type format: %d\n",wave_type_format);

if(wave_type_format!=1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error! WAVE type format should be 1\n");
    return 1;
}

//read bytes 23-24 for mono stereo
    for(i=0; i<2; i++) {
            buffer2[i] = getchar();
    }
    mono_stereo = buffer2[0] | (buffer2[1]<<8);
    fprintf(stderr, "mono/stereo: %d\n",mono_stereo);

if(mono_stereo!=1 && mono_stereo!=2) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error! mono/stereo should be 1 or 2\n");
    return 1;
}

//read bytes 25-28 for sample rate
    for(i=0; i<4; i++) {
            buffer4[i] = getchar();
    }
    sample_rate = buffer4[0] | (buffer4[1]<<8) | (buffer4[2]<<16) | (buffer4[3]<<24);
    fprintf(stderr, "sample rate: %d\n",sample_rate);

//read bytes 29-32 for bytes per second
    for(i=0; i<4; i++) {
            buffer4[i] = getchar();
    }
    bytes_per_second = buffer4[0] | (buffer4[1]<<8) | (buffer4[2]<<16) | (buffer4[3]<<24);
    fprintf(stderr, "bytes/sec: %d\n",bytes_per_second);

//read bytes 33-34 for block alignment
    for(i=0; i<2; i++) {
            buffer2[i] = getchar();
    }
    block_alignment = buffer2[0] | (buffer2[1]<<8);
    fprintf(stderr, "block alignment: %d\n",block_alignment);

if(bytes_per_second!=sample_rate*block_alignment) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error! bytes/second should be sample rate x block alignment\n");
    return 1;
}

//read bytes 35-36 for bits per sample
    for(i=0; i<2; i++) {
            buffer2[i] = getchar();
    }
    bits_per_sample = buffer2[0] | (buffer2[1]<<8);
    fprintf(stderr, "bits/sample: %d\n",bits_per_sample);

if(bits_per_sample!=8 && bits_per_sample!=16) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error! bits/sample should be 8 or 16\n");
    return 0;
}

if(block_alignment!=bits_per_sample/8*mono_stereo) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error! block alignment should be bits per sample / 8 x mono/stereo\n");
    return 1;
}

//read bytes 37-40 to check data
    for(i=0; i<4; i++) {
            data[i] = getchar();
    }

    if(data[0] != 'd') {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error! \"data\" not found\n");
            return 1; 
    } else if(data[1] != 'a') {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error! \"data\" not found\n");
            return 1; 
    } else if(data[2] != 't') {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error! \"data\" not found\n");
            return 1; 
    } else if(data[3] != 'a') {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error! \"data\" not found\n");
            return 1;
    }

//read bytes 41-44 for bytes per second
    for(i=0; i<4; i++) {
            buffer4[i] = getchar();
    }
    size_of_data_chunck = buffer4[0] | (buffer4[1]<<8) | (buffer4[2]<<16) | (buffer4[3]<<24);
    fprintf(stderr, "size of data chunck: %d\n",size_of_data_chunck);

//check if file size is correct
i=44;
while(getchar()!=EOF)
    i++;

if(i!=size_of_file+8) {
    fprintf(stderr,"Error! bad file size\n");
    return 1;
}

return 0;
}
```

The question is how to double sound's speed and create a new wav file?

Comment: You forgot to ask a question

Comment: You read entire input with the first `while` so all of the following `getchar()` calls will return `EOF`. You can write a function that will echo each character to output and return it: `int mygetc() { int c = getchar(); if (c != EOF) putchar(c); return c; }` Now replace every call to `getchar()` in your code with `mygetc()`.

Comment: Given `char c;`, `if(c == EOF)` can't work reliably.  `EOF` is an `int`, not a `char`, and `getchar()` returns `int` for that reason.  `c` **must** be an `int`.

Comment: Sorry, the while loop is a test for me to copy a wav file. By the way it write plain text instead of binary file.

Comment: The code that deals with checking of RIFF, WAVE etc. is really weird. It this code was rewritten properly it would be roughly 5-6 times shorter. You should do something like `if (strncmp(fmt, "fmt ", 4) {fprintf(stderr, "Error!....`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First. Unless you're doing this as a pure exercise, you should not write such things from scratch. You should use a library. There exists a few out there.

> The question is how to double sound's speed and create a new wav file?

The absolute easiest way to achieve this is to simply double the sample rate. Write everything else just as it is to a new file, but double the sample rate first and it will be played with double speed.

If you want to try it out, get a hexeditor and just edit the sample rate field.

But please note that this approach "works". In order to do it correctly, you should also modify the ByteRate field, which comes right after the SampleRate field. I skipped that part.

Here is a very small example that does the job:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(void)
{
    // Copy everything before sample rate
    for(size_t i=0; i<24; i++)
        putchar(getchar());

    // Read the sample rate
    unsigned char b[4];
    for(size_t i=0; i<4; i++)
        b[i] = getchar();

    // Double it
    uint32_t sr = b[0] | (b[1]<<8) | (b[2]<<16) | (b[3]<<24);
    sr *= 2;

    // Write the doubled rate
    for(size_t i=0; i<4; i++)
        putchar((sr >> i*8) & 0xFF);

    // Copy the rest
    int ch;
    while((ch = getchar()) != EOF)
        putchar(ch);
}
```

Please note that this is VERY minimal. I have completely skipped any error checking. If the sample rate is too high, then this will not work.

The above is a non-destructive method. If you want to keep the sample rate, then you need to remove information. I'm not sure how to do it, but I guess you could take the average of two samples. Or maybe just skip every other. If I have to guess, I think the best approach is to do something like:

```
new_sample = exp(log(sample1) + log(sample2))
```

But I have not tried it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I know that I have to double the sample rate but the problem is that I can't write the result in a new file with only use putchar method.

Comment: @FalierisIlias I updated with a working example